# Finding the result of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you find the exact result of this sum:
$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}\quad \text{where}\;\; \vert x \vert <1 \;.$$

Comment: Hint: Find a closed formula for the sum without the $i$ denominators, and integrate term-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinte sum for geometric series is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x} \qquad ;|x|<1
\end{equation}

take $\int dx $ on both sides then

On left hand side :
\begin{equation}\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int x^{n-1}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n}
\end{equation}

On right hand side :
\begin{equation}\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx=-\ln(1-x)+C \end{equation}
Thus

\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n}=-\ln(1-x)+C \end{equation}
We can see that for $x=0$ , constant $C$ is $0$

Finally we have
\begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n}=-\ln(1-x) \qquad;|x|<1 \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

If we can use calculus, you could first try differentiating the function to obtain

$$S'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Now, using the definition of the logarithm, integrating gives

$$\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx=-\log(1-x)+C,$$

so that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}=-\log(1-x)+C$.

Now let $x=0$ to obtain $0=-\log(1)+C\implies C=0$, so that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i}=-\log(1-x).\tag{$|x|<1$}$$

Comment: why did you integrate that other sum? I can't understaund their link

Comment: Basically I know that if I differentiate the first sum I will get something I recognize to have a closed form. But I don't want a closed form for the derivative... I want a closed form for the original sum, which is the integral of the derivative. So I just integrate the derivative which I have in closed form. But the integral is just equal to the original sum. I haven't actually integrated any sums at all. I have just differentiated the first sum and then integrated its closed form and set equal to the original sum.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: this question is closed as you can see

Comment: That's no reason to methodically downvote every element of a question though.

Answer (score 0):

The power series of $x \, \mapsto \, \ln(1-x)$ is :

$$ \forall x \in (-1,1), \quad \ln(1-x) = - \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n}. $$

Therefore, for all $x \in (-1,1)$, $S(x) = - \ln(1-x)$.